# What is the difference between `?` and the name of the query in Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that the first query is safe:

```
foo.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
```

but I am not sure about the second?

```
foo.where('name Like :search', search: "%#{search}%")
```

Comment: The only real difference is that the `:name` version is easier to read when there are multiple parameter or if one parameter is used multiple times in the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second is safe too. Check out the examples in the `ActiveRecord::Sanitization::ClassMethods`: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html

For example:

```
sanitize_sql_array(["name=? and group_id=?", "foo'bar", 4])
# => "name='foo''bar' and group_id=4"

sanitize_sql_array(["name=:name and group_id=:group_id", name: "foo'bar", group_id: 4])
# => "name='foo''bar' and group_id=4"

sanitize_sql_array(["name='%s' and group_id='%s'", "foo'bar", 4])
# => "name='foo''bar' and group_id='4'"
```

Answer (score 3):

Both `'name LIKE ?'` and `'name Like :search'` use prepared statements which escape the values and are thus safe from an SQL injection attack unlike `"name LIKE %#{search}%"` which uses string concatenation.

The only difference is how the bound variables are declared. `?` is a positional placeholder, while `:search` is a named placeholder.

The use of positional or named placeholders only really impacts to the readability of your code.

```
# really no point in a named placeholder here
Foo.where('a = ?', 1)
Foo.where('a = :a', a: 1)

# positional arguments can get confusing if there a lot of them
Foo.where('a = ? AND b = ? AND c = ?', 1, 2, 3)
Foo.where('a = :a AND b = :b AND c = :c', a: 1, b: 2, c: 3)

# this is where a named placeholder shines
Foo.where('a = ? AND (b = ? OR c = ?)', foo.name, foo.name, foo.id)
Foo.where('a = :name AND (b = :id OR c = :name)', name: foo.name, id: foo.id)
```

The design considerations are very similar to the use of positional vs named arguments in methods.